# Python - Return list of dictionaries with unique Key:Value pair

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, unique

I have a long list of dictionaries that for the most part do not overlap. However, some of the dictionaries have the same 'Name' field and I'd only like unique names in the list of dictionaries. I'd like the first occurrence of the name to be the one that stays and any thereafter be deleted from the list.

I've put a short list below to illustrate the scenario:

```
myList = [
    {'Name':'John', 'Age':'50', 'Height':'70'},
    {'Name':'Kathy', 'Age':'43', 'Height':'65'},
    {'Name':'John','Age':'46','Height':'68'},
    {'Name':'John','Age':'50','Height':'72'}
]
```

I'd like this list to return the **first** 'John' and Kathy, but not the second or third Johns and their related information.

An acceptable, but not optimal solution would also be not having dictionaries with the same name next to each other.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at solving this problem on your own?  You'll generally get much better responses / reception here at StackOverflow if you show us your attempts, rather than just providing a problem scope with a sample input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run over the list and keep a `set` of unique names. Every time you encounter a new name (i.e., a name that isn't in the set), you add it to the set and the respective dict to the result:

```
def uniqueNames(dicts):
    names = set()
    result = []
    for d in dicts:
        if not d['Name'] in names:
            names.add(d['Name'])
            result.append(d)
    return result
```

Comment: `set`s do not guarantee that that the elements are in order. This makes the answer irrelevant because OP wants the *first* occurence of the name.

Comment: @u8y7541 read the answer again - the set is only used to track uniqueness. The order comes from iterating the input list, and the the result list preserves the same order.

Comment: if not d['Name'] in names:

That's exactly what I was looking for. I've never used that before

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write a for-loop for this.

```
 def getName(name):
    '''Gets first occurence of name in list of dicts.'''
    for i in myList:
        if i['Name'] == name:
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial list:

```
my_list = [
    {'Name':'John', 'Age':'50', 'Height':'70'},
    {'Name':'Kathy', 'Age':'43', 'Height':'65'},
    {'Name':'John','Age':'46','Height':'68'},
    {'Name':'John','Age':'50','Height':'72'}
]
```

The logical (potentially newbie-friendlier) way:

```
names = set()
new_list = []
for d in my_list:
    name = d['Name']
    if name not in names:
        new_list.append(d)
        names.add(d['Name'])
print new_list  # [{'Age': '50', 'Name': 'John', 'Height': '70'}, {'Age': '43', 'Name': 'Kathy', 'Height': '65'}]
```

A one-liner way:

```
new_list = {d['Name']: d for d in reversed(my_list)}.values()
print new_list  # [{'Age': '43', 'Name': 'Kathy', 'Height': '65'}, {'Age': '50', 'Name': 'John', 'Height': '70'}]
```

**Note**: The one-liner will contain the first occurrence of each name, but it will return an arbitrarily ordered list.